# Elementary OS 5.0 Juno grub installation error [Single Boot]

Tags: system-installation, grub

I have Asus laptop with 24GB SSD and 1TB HDD and the main idea was to use all SSD space for `/` and 10GB HDD space for `Swap` and rest of the HDD space for `/home` partition.

Going through the installation when asked about installation type I chose *'Something else'* and managed partitions on my own following the main idea and placing `Swap` and `/home` partitions as logical and `/` as primary. All HDD partitions were on `/dev/sda` and SSD partition was on `/dev/sdb`.

In *'Device for bootloader installation'* dropdown I chose `/dev/sdb` as there was my `/` partition and went through with the installation.

All went well until grub tried to be installed - I got message:

`Executing 'grub-install /dev/sdb' failed. Fatal Error.`.

Now I am not sure what could have gone sideways and I would appreciate the help.

Also it got me thinking do I even need grub bootloader if I am planning on having **only** Elementary OS installed on my laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE]

I managed to fix the problem.

The problem was in a single boot. When you have Windows installed and are trying to have dual boot, as far as I understand, you do not ran into problem like this because Windows creates boot partition automatically, but when you install single boot Linux you have to do this on your own.

I got it to work by splitting SSD space into two partitions: EFI partition that takes 200MB, and the rest of the space for ext4 `/` partition.

For *Device for bootloader installation* I chose `/dev/sdb1` which is my EFI partition. Then I started the installation and everything worked.

Hope this helps.